# Name Resolution Failed for Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I'm using an EC2 server in conjunction with Route53.
However, despite my best efforts, I cannot understand why the DNS is failing to resolve.
What I have done so far:

1. Ensured the domain and hosted zone share the same NS
2. Set up an elastic IP for EC2 and added an A record with that info
3. Opened up all traffic on all ip addresses in my security group within EC2
4. waited for propagation
5. Made sure I was using my www address for testing

I can access the site using the elastic IP itself, which tells me the security group isn't the issue.
Here's screenshots of my [Hosted Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv2Wg.png) and [Name Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEIy9.png). 
Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you click on the *row* of the hosted zone in the list of the hosted zones in the console -- selecting the row, but not clicking on the actual link that takes you into the hosted zone, there are 4 nameservers listed on the right side of the screen.  Do *those* match also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to now be working, albeit only on cellular. Looks like I just need to wait for my ISP to do their thing, despite being over 72 hours now.